# getting an error trying to fetch token from Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

i created a separate xamarin app and trying to fetch token after login. I am following code snippet similar to what is mentioned here

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/

in my Tenant settings are like this

[image]

my redirect URL is also formatted properly like

```
 PCA.RedirectUri = $"msal{GlobalSetting.Instance.ClientID}://auth";
```

but

```
IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(GlobalSetting.Instance.Scopes, GetAccountByPolicy(accounts, GlobalSetting.Instance.PolicySignUpSignIn), App.UiParent);
```

this call takes me to Azure AD b2c pages and i have configured facebook there. After going through the facebook login it shows me the error

this big url and then 
**"could not be loaded because
net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"**

[image]

my android manifest file looks like this

```
    <application android:label="HaveThat" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon">
    <application> 
    <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="msald6b07784-0e3a-483a-9exxxxxxc524ed1d" android:host="auth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

**UPDATE**

after removing the inner application block its not showing the web page with error. instead it is showing a blank screen in my application and next line in the code is also not hitting.

[image]

Comment: Have you configured the Android and/or iOS project with the `msalXXX://auth` redirect URI? See steps 6a and 6b in the referenced article.

Comment: yes check my update. i dont have 

"//auth" at the end though.

Comment: i also observed that i am using 2 application blocks ? may be thats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix was to use true as a second parameter in UIParent

```
           App.UiParent = new UIParent(this, true);
```

this tells the system to use embedded browser.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I had this exact same issue. It turned out that in the Azure portal's AD app registrations I had not selected the checkbox for the MSAL redirect URI.

This is accessed by clicking on the application's redirect URIs within the application registration. This should bring you to a page with your redirect URIs listed. Select the checkboxes of the redirect URIs you want to be able to access, and you should be good to go.